# Extract data from string

Tags: php, regex

```
$str= 'We have new Call Request: Reference = 55823014, Name = Amal, Mobile = 111111'
```

How do i extract this part from the string like:

```
reference |  55823014
Name      |  Amal
Mobile    |  1111111
```

Comment: output must be variables or array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use Regular Expressions to extract that

```
$str= 'We have new Call Request: Reference = 55823014, Name = Amal, Mobile = 111111';

preg_match('/Reference =(.*?), Name =(.*?), Mobile =(.*)/', $str, $m);

print_r($m);
//if you want to display an item at a time

echo "Reference = ".$m[1].PHP_EOL;
echo "Name = ".$m[2].PHP_EOL;
echo "Mobile = ".$m[3].PHP_EOL;
```

this will give you

```
Array
(
    [0] => Reference = 55823014, Name = Amal, Mobile = 111111
    [1] =>  55823014
    [2] =>  Amal
    [3] =>  111111
)
Reference =  55823014
Name =  Amal
Mobile =  111111
```

**[Demo](http://ideone.com/ZAsvUs)**

Answer (score 1):

First you remove the text 'We have new Call Request:' from the string. Then you are left with the main string that contains the key value pairs. From that, you explode it into an array of tokens by comma where each token contains one key value pair. Then you loop through the tokens and separate out the key value by exploding it with equal to '=' sign. Here's the code for it:

```
<?php
$str = 'We have new Call Request: Reference = 55823014, Name = Amal, Mobile = 111111';
$str = substr($str, strpos($str, ':') + 1);
$arr = explode(',', $str);
$data = array();
foreach ($arr as $item) {
    $tokens = explode('=', $item);
    $key = trim($tokens[0]);
    $val = trim($tokens[1]);
    $data[$key] = $val;
}
var_dump($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay as a quick approach, this should work:

```
$str= 'We have new Call Request: Reference = 55823014, 
       Name = Amal, Mobile = 111111';
$str = strchr($str, "Reference");
$str = explode(',', $str);

foreach ($str as $item) {
$tokens = explode('=', $item);
$key = trim($tokens[0]);
$val = trim($tokens[1]);
echo $key . " | " . $val . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
Reference | 55823014
Name | Amal
Mobile | 111111
```